# Flutter Firebase handle with Back button

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to learn Flutter. I have the google sign in registration and if my user is not in the database he had to give a username to go into the app and be in the database. If the user clicked on the back button, an instance is in the database but without username.
Is it possible, if the user clicked on the back button, to have a function to delete the document in the database?I tried a lot but it doesn't work. How can I handle with this button?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: show your code ...

Answer (score 1):

you can add the following code on the `onPressed:` method of the button like this

```
onPressed:(){

final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    firestore.doc(documentPath).delete();
}
```

Here document path means the reference to the users document
ex `user/<uniquid>`